# Script ignores set to false

Tags: input, signals, modulus, godot, gdscript

Here's a mock-up of my script:

```
# player.gd

extends HBoxContainer

class_name Player

var can_play = false

signal thing

func _ready():
    connect("thing", #the following script# , "stuff")

func _input(Input):
    if !can_play:
        return
    emit_signal("thing")
```

```
# game.gd

extends Node

var players = [Player0, Player1, Player2, Player3] # of class Player
var current_player = 0

func _ready():
    yadda()

func yadda():
    players[current_player].can_play = true

func stuff():
    players[current_player].can_play = false

    print(players[current_player])

    current_player = (current_player + 1) % 4
    
    yadda()
```

My goal here is to have each player get their name printed when it's their turn and on input. Only one player should have their can_play set to true. On every input, the current player has their can_play set to false and the next one set to true.

Now this code works every time except when current_player == 3. If there's an input after that, the code prints both "Player3" and "Player0". Player3 and Player0 have their can_play set to true one after the other with only one input. This doesn't happen for the other Players either.

I have tried setting a Timer so that the code doesn't set can_play to true directly and it was successful. The real problem here is that I don't understand why the code wouldn't work only on Player3 and Player0

Comment: Hi, can you post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to test?

Comment: @hola sure, here you go https://gofile.io/d/9A6681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by event propagation. Input events bubble up the tree starting from the deepest leaf nodes.

### Explanation

```
Main        ^
  - Player0 |
  - Player1 | _input(event)
  - Player2 |
  - Player3 |
```

The situation is when `Player3` `can_play` and the left click input event begins propagating up the scene tree.

1. `Player3` receives the left click input event. It `can_play` and signals to `Main` to do `stuff()`.

   - `stuff()` sets `can_play` to false.
   - `stuff()` sets `current_player` to the next player, `Player0`.
2. `Player2` receives the left click input event. It can't play.
3. `Player1` receives the left click input event. It can't play.
4. `Player0` receives the left click input event. It `can_play` and signals to `Main` to do `stuff()`.

   - **This is the issue.**
5. `Main` receives the left click input event.

### Solution

Call `SceneTree.set_input_as_handled()` after handling the input event.

```
if input.is_action_pressed("left_click") and can_play:
    emit_signal("thing")
    get_tree().set_input_as_handled()
```

### Tip

```
# Player.gd
func _ready():
    connect("thing", get_parent(), "stuff")
```

The `thing` signal connection here should be connected by the parent. For example:

```
# Main.gd
func _ready():
    for player in players:
        player.connect("thing", self, "stuff")
```

This decouples `Player.gd` from `Main.gd`. `Player.gd` no longer needs to know about the method `stuff()`.

Generally, signals go up the scene tree and method calls go down the scene tree.